# Nodejs request stream - manipulating cookie before response piping

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, stream

I have a Express proxy that uses request NPM module to make CRUD calls to a remote server. On the response, I do cookie manipulation to change the path. This is the code here.

```
    request({
        method: req.method,
        url: proxyUrl,
        jar: jar,
        headers: headers,
        json: jsonBody,
    }, function(error, response, body) {

        if (error && response.statusCode !== 201 || response.statusCode !== 200) {
            logger.info("proxying failed - reason: " + error);
            return res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
        };
        var cookies = jar.getCookies(proxyUrl);
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i];
            if (cookie.path !== "/") {
                cookie.path = "/"; //change path from /api to /
                cookie.secure = (os.hostname().indexOf("local") > -1 ? false : true);
            }
            res.cookie(cookie);
        };
        res.headers = response.headers;
        return res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
    });
```

This works fine.
But now, NodeJs comes with streams. So, I write this piece of code to achieve the same with nodejs streams.

```
    req.pipe(
        request({
            method:req.method,
            url: proxyUrl,
            jar: jar,
            json:req.body

        })).on("response", function(response) {
        var cookies = jar.getCookies(proxyUrl);
        console.log(cookies);
        if (response.statusCode === 201 || response.statusCode === 200 || response.statusCode === 202) {
            logger.info("successfully proxied");

            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i];
                if (cookie.path !== "/") {
                    cookie.path = "/"; //change path from /api to /
                    cookie.secure = (os.hostname().indexOf("local") > -1 ? false : true);
                }
                jar.setCookie(cookie, proxyUrl);
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("proxying failed - reason: " + error || "refer body");
        }
    }).pipe(res)
```

This doesn't change the cookie path.
Request implements tough.cookie. So, if I mainpulate the cookie jar, it's stored in the request's response and hence shouldn't it be piped all the way to express's response?